# No MessageContext available when using Autofac together with Rebus

Tags: autofac, rebus

I get a InvalidOperationException on the code below.  I am sure my lack of knowledge about autofac IoC and Rebus is giving me this error.

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled

Message=No message context available - the MessageContext instance will only be set during the handling of messages, and it is available only on the worker thread.

part of the StackTrace:

```
at Rebus.MessageContext.GetCurrent()
at Rebus.Autofac.AutofacContainerAdapter.GetHandlerInstancesFor[T]()
at RebusAutofacDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\RebusAutofacDemo\Program.cs:line 45
[cut]
```

So when I use the code below in a Console Application, I get the error above.

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<MyHandler>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        var adapter = new AutofacContainerAdapter(container);
        var bus = Configure.With(adapter)
            .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus("myConnectionstring", "my_input_queue", "error"))
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();

        adapter.GetHandlerInstancesFor<MyHandler>();  // THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR

        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += delegate { bus.SendLocal(new MyMessage{ Body = DateTime.Now.ToString()}); };
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyMessage
{
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class MyHandler : IHandleMessages<MyMessage>
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;
    public MyHandler(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
    }

    public void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

for completeness this was added to the app.config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="rebus" type="Rebus.Configuration.RebusConfigurationSection, Rebus" />
</configSections>

<rebus inputQueue="my-app.input" errorQueue="my-app.error" workers="1">
  <endpoints>
    <!-- <add messages="SomeAssembly" endpoint="another-app.input"/> -->
  </endpoints>
</rebus>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the error because you're calling `GetHandlerInstances` which is meant to be called by Rebus when handling a message.

Try removing that line and then you'll see that your message gets handled.

PS: `MyHandler` must be registered in the container as an implementation of `IHandleMessages<MyMessage>` - I'm not an expert on Autofac, but I don't think you're doing that in your code...?

Comment: I removed the line, and changed the builder to : builder.RegisterType<MyHandler>().AsImplementedInterfaces();  Now it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Worth noting that Autofac can scan the assembly for handlers.  This will register all interfaces: `b.RegisterAssemblyTypes(MyAssembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()`.  More in the docs [here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html).

Comment: Just uploaded an example of using Autofac's Modules to register Rebus Handlers [here](https://github.com/seankearon/rebus-autofac-module).